# Paypal Express Checkout Full Discount

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using Express Checkout in Paypal and trying to pass discount as a separate item taking reference as [Paypal Express Checkout provide full items discount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937861/paypal-express-checkout-provide-full-items-discount)

```
&L_NAME0=Item1
&L_NAME1=Discount
&L_AMT0=1.01
&L_AMT1=-50
&L_QTY0=50
&L_QTY1=1
&MAXAMT=27.51
&AMT=2.51
&ITEMAMT=0.01
&TAXAMT = 2.5
```

According to the above parameter my Item Amount is getting 0 and i've added 0.01 as mentioned in the reference. 
It is like :

```
Item Cost = 50.00
Tax = 2.5
Discount = 50.00
```

But I get

> "The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts."

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks